# C#: AmbiguousMatchException: ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oop, mvvm

I get the exception:

> AmbiguousMatchException: ambiguous match found

when opening my Window and the XAML gets parsed. I have a base ViewModel class. It has a property for the SelectedItem property of a DataGrid

```
public class BaseViewModel<T> : ViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : MyClass
{
    protected T _selectedItem;
    public T SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In my inherited ViewModel I override that property which produces the exception

```
public new MyInheritedClass SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

So how to use the overrided property and not get an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you redefining the property in the derived class? The type argument of the derived class should specify the type of the property:

```
public class MyInheritedClass : BaseViewModel<MyClass>
{
    //no need to define a new SelectedItem property...
}
```

In the above sample code `MyInheritedClass` already has a `SelectedItem` property of type `MyClass`. It is already defined in the base class. You don't need to create a new one.

If the property needs to do something special in the derived class, you should define the property as `virtual` in the base class:

```
public virtual T SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

...and override it in the derived class:

```
public override MyClass SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I need to do something special for that inherited class. Look at the comment in the new property

Comment: Then you should make the property virtual in the base class and override it in the derived class. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, if you define a Property (or the accessor of a Dependency property) which already exists in the base class. Because then you make it ambigious. Either you have to override (Topic: virtual) or new (hide) it. Otherwise the reflection happenings in WPF will deal with ambiguity.

Example:

```
public partial class My : UserControl
{
// this will make the ambiguity with the existing trigges-DP legacy accessor
public int Triggers {get;set;}

// this will not make ambiguities, because it hides the original.
// however it may cause other problems
public new object Background {get;set; }

// also OK, but needs justification as well.
public override object ExistingVirtualProperty {get;set; }
...
```